# Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform | flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

How to fix this,

error says,
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following StateError was thrown building:
Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

Another problem is when the user searches for something, the app should show the username without considering capital, simple words

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';
import 'package:insta/utils/colors.dart';

class SearchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SearchScreen> createState() => _SearchScreenState();
}

class _SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen> {
  final TextEditingController searchCon = TextEditingController();
  bool isShowUsers = false;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    searchCon.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
        title: TextFormField(
          controller: searchCon,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            labelText: "Search for a user",
          ),
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              isShowUsers = true;
            });
          },
          // onFieldSubmitted: (String _) {
          //   setState(() {
          //     isShowUsers = true;
          //   });
          // },
        ),
      ),
      body: isShowUsers
          ? FutureBuilder(
              future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('users')
                  .where(
                    'username',
                    isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: searchCon.text,
                  )
                  .get(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: (snapshot.data! as dynamic).docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      leading: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                            (snapshot.data! as dynamic).docs[index]
                                ['photoUrl']),
                      ),
                      title: Text(
                          (snapshot.data! as dynamic).docs[index]['username']),
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            )
          : FutureBuilder(
              future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts').get(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(child: const CircularProgressIndicator());
                }

                return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  itemCount: (snapshot.data! as dynamic).docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Image.network(
                    (snapshot.data! as dynamic).docs[index]['postUrl'],
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                  staggeredTileBuilder: (index) => StaggeredTile.count(
                      (index % 7 == 0) ? 2 : 1, (index % 7 == 0) ? 2 : 1),
                  mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                );
              },
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Got this error while working with firebase its due to when you are trying to access the document doesn't exist or check the spelling, syntax when you access them